# Memory leak updating geometry - ArcGis Runtime .Net

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, map-drawing, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, graphics

i'm working with ArcGis Runtime SDK for .Net v10.2.5.

I have an UDP socket listening and waiting for image data that fires a function executed on a different thread in background.

I want to draw the image over a ellipse of arbitrary radius so i use

```
var filestream = System.IO.File.Open(imagepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
MapPoint point = new MapPoint(center.longitude, center.latitude, SpatialReferences.Wgs84);

var polySymbol = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Symbology.PictureFillSymbol();                    
await polySymbol.SetSourceAsync(filestream);

var param = new GeodesicEllipseParameters(point, 25, LinearUnits.Meters);
var ellipse = GeometryEngine.GeodesicEllipse(param);

***//HERE IS THE PROBLEM***   
_graphicsLayer.Graphics.Clear();
_graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(new Graphic { Geometry = ellipse, Symbol = polySymbol });
```

This is done ~5 times/second. Despite i'm clearing the layer each iteration there is a memory leak that is increasing memory use till app crashes.

I read about problems with memory using ArcGIS and Geometry process, so i'm not sure if i'm hitting a wall or just doing things badly